# Can't get the value from input using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value from an input tag in HTML using JavaScript but I always get undefined. Help me solve this issue..

HTML code is as follows

```
<td><input type="text" class="number cost" value="10000"></td>
```

JavaScript is as follows

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cost").value;
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Try `document.getElementsByClassName("cost")[0].value`

Comment: @Shilly — While array-like, the object returned is **not** an array.

Comment: Yeah, i know, it's a live collection of nodes, but I was trying to keep it simple as the OP is a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns to you an *array-like object*, So if you have one item, it will return an one item in the *array-like object*. Get the first item by its index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cost")[0].value;
```